# Let $G$ and $H$ be groups, and let $X:G\to H$ be a group homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be groups, and let $X : G\to H$ be a group homomorphism. Prove the
following statements.

A. If $K$ is a subgroup of  $H$, then $X^{-1}
(K)$ is a subgroup of $G$.

B. If $K$ is normal in $H$, then $X^{-1}(K)$ is normal in $G$.

C. If $X$ is surjective and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $X (N)$ is a normal
subgroup of $H$.

Comment: I figured out A and B need direction on C

Answer (score 1):

We must show $hX(N)h^{-1} \subseteq X(N)$ for all $h \in H$.  Let $hxh^{-1} \in hX(N)h^{-1}$.   We can find $a \in N, b \in G$ such that $X(a) = x$ and $X(b)= h$.  By normality, $bab^{-1} \in X(N)$.

I'll leave the rest to you.